# Python get ALL possible combinations from lists

Tags: python, unique, combinations, python-itertools

I know there are several questions like this, but they dont describe exactly what I want. I need it for a task about a password generator. All itertools modules I know work like:

`list1 = [1, 2]`
`list2 = [3, 4]`

it would print out: `(1, 3)(1, 4)(2, 3)(2, 4)`

But I also need `(3, 1)(4, 1)(3, 2)(4, 2)`
´
So basically `(1, 0)` and `(0, 1)` shouldnt be seen as the same combination.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Would `itertools.permutations` do what you want? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: And one more thing: I somehow cannot join the tuples I get from itertools.combinations. They are all strings, with .join I get an empty output (it prints as many blank lines as passwords were generated) and if I do it with a for loop i get completely weird outputs, it for example prints the alphabet as many times as passwords were generated

Comment: @JonBetts yes, this is exactly what I want, thank you! But still I cannot concat them to a string

Answer (score -1):

As per your need, I've constructed a program :

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [3, 4]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        print((i,j),end=' ')
    for j in list2:
        print((j,i),end=" ")
```

Comment: Thank you, but am I right that using itertools.permutations with one list with [1, 2, 3, 4] would do the same?

Comment: What I actually forgot is that I also need things like aa, bb, cc etc, but i currently have no clue how to do all that efficient